# Add Kyrgyz Language to WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to Kyrgyz Language on WordPress, but in Language menu is no Kyrgyz Language. How can I Kyrgyz Language?
What is Kyrgyz Language code?

Answer (score 0):

Kyrgyz language

ISO 639-1 **ky**
ISO 639-2, ISO 639-3 **kir**

Look at this
[WordPress - Kyrgyz](https://wordpress.com/forums/topic/kyrgyz-language/)

my sources: google, wikipedia, Internet

Comment: @Wonderlancer I mean - look, try, if not working ask there - here no one knows how to do it, and someone voted down, because you didn't try to help yourself. Language code is easy to find.